# Is this question about a DIY vehicle on topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/64174/diy-vehicle-not-moving) is about a DIY vehicle electric vehicle. I came across it in review, but I don't really know what to do with it to be honest

Would this be on topic for this site? I wasn't sure whether to vote to close it or not

Answer (score 3):

I get where you're coming from. It is a *different* kind of question, that's for sure. My gut check here is to let it stand, though I say that as a user here, not as a mod. If the community says to close it, then so be it.

The reason my gut check tells me to keep it open has several reasons:

1. While not your typical question, it is about a motor powered vehicle.
2. There isn't anything which states a DIY question off-topic (this question could prove this otherwise, though)
3. It's an interesting question to me in that it is different than normal. This in and of itself is not a reason to keep it, however, it does have some intrigue to it.

Again, this is JMHO, so I'm more than willing to bow to the community if they believe it needs to be closed. As it stands, if you believe it should be closed, please tag it as such.